# Abnormalities in Qml spline chart

Tags: qt, charts, qml, spline

When creating a spline chart, it is getting loops inside the chart and some portions are going beyond the chart panel. Please find the below code

```
 ChartView {
    title: "Spline"
    anchors.fill: parent
    antialiasing: true

    SplineSeries {
        name: "SplineSeries"
        XYPoint { x: 154593917; y: 612.5 }
        XYPoint { x: 154594277; y: 425 }
        XYPoint { x: 154594632; y: 437 }
        XYPoint { x: 154594997; y: 460 }
        XYPoint { x: 154595357; y: 506 }
        XYPoint { x: 154596073; y: 513 }
        XYPoint { x: 154596437; y: 527 }
        XYPoint { x: 154596797; y: 575 }
        XYPoint { x: 154597517; y: 632 }
        XYPoint { x: 154597877; y: 369 }
        XYPoint { x: 154598237; y: 410 }
        XYPoint { x: 154598851; y: 414 }
        XYPoint { x: 154604971; y: 633 }
        XYPoint { x: 154605331; y: 598 }
        XYPoint { x: 154605400; y: 500 }
    }
}
```

How to remove this looping? Please help

[image]

Comment: try LineSeries instead to see that all the points are in some incremental order, ie. no loops etc.

Comment: Well it's a spline. It's not as "abnormal" as it is its nature to behave like that. But what sort of curve were you expecting? Consider annotating your screenshot further with your expected results. On another note, have you tried folibis's idea of a LineSeries?

Comment: I want to remove this loops inside the chart. Ideally it should not come. I have not tried folibis's idea of a LineSeries. Please share more details

Comment: @folibis: The data in the question is in correct, incremental order.

Answer (score 5):

The problem comes from the fact that `SplineSeries` is creating, well, a [spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) (piecewise polynomials) to interpolate your points. QtCharts doesn't provide any control on spline parameters, such as degree, control points, etc. All of them are automatically computed from the dataset.

You should take care of the nature of the spline: they will *pass through* the data points, but the rest of the points will be approximated by the under-the-hood polynomial function, so creating *unexpected points*. In order to create the piecewise curve, some constraints must be met, such as C<sup>0</sup>, C<sup>1</sup> and C<sup>2</sup> [continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Continuity_levels) (assuming a cubic spline). In your case, the curve must create these *loops* in order to meet such constraints.

QtCharts doesn't provide many XY plotting options: basically `ScatterSeries` (plots single points), `LineSeries` (linear interpolation, no options for smoothing) and `SplineSeries` (smooth, spline-based interpolation).

To use another one, just replace the node `SplineSeries` by `LineSeries`. Here you have an example of how they look like with your data:

[image: series comparison]

As a mid-point solution, you can preprocess your data using some other interpolating method that better adapts to your requirements (such a [composite Bèzier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_B%C3%A9zier_curve)), and then evaluate the curve in more points to create a smoother data, more friendly with `SplineSeries` or, if it looks good-enough for you, that can be directly rendered using `LinesSeries`.

Comment: I've used Maya in the past when it didn't support Bezier curves, just splines, and the trick to making a sharp corner using those was to represent sharp corners with 3 points in immediate proximiti, although this is not really applicable in a data chart scenario.